# How to call REST WCF service from android client

Tags: c#, android, wcf, rest

I am working in a project where I have to access backend service  for user authentication from Android client application. Therefore, I have created a WCF REST service which has the following structure.

```
    //<summary>
    // Checks whether user is exists or not
    // </summary>
    // <param name="UserName"></param>
    // <param name="Password"></param>
    // <returns></returns>

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "IsUserExist/{UserName}/{Password}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    bool IsUserExist(string UserName, string Password);


    // <summary>
    // Log the time of specified user
    // </summary>
    // <param name="UserName"></param>
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "LogTime/{username}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string LogTime(string UserName);
```

And I have successfully deployed it in IIS. And I can easily call the service from browser to perform user authentication, which worked fine.

```
http://localhost:9001/HNNDataSerivce/LogInService.svc/IsUserExist/Bob/pass123
http://localhost:9001/HNNDataSerivce/LogInService.svc/LogTime/Bob
```

And this service call returns the desired value as boolean and string respectively.

Now I would like to make  same service call from an android client. For that I have created a simple demo application with a textbox and button. Where user specified username and password in textboxes and when an user clicks the button I want to implement the following authentication process.

```
    public void LoginButtonClick(View v) {
    if(IsUserExist(UserName, Password))
        LogTime(UserName)
    else
    // show invalid user message

}
```

Comment: look into retrofit for android

Comment: As an aside question: why is a **Login** method called IsUserExists?

Comment: @cFrozenDeath, the reason behind calling IsUserExists, is to make sure that whether the specified user is exists in the database or not. And if it is exists, then LogTime function will be invoked to log the time of logging.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple REST client library that you can call from Android. There is an Android sample included.

https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/RestClient.Net

The code is all open source so you can just grab the bits you need if necessary.

Edit: the repo was moved from Bitbucket to Github

Comment: I have fixed the link now